# How to display a custom SQL query as a template loop in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to get the following SQL query to display as a Silverstripe loop:

```
public function FilteredCompanyDivisions($SectionID)
{
  $query = DB::query(
    'SELECT "CompanyDivision"."Title", "Office_CompanyDivisions"."DivisionPhoneNumber"
    FROM "CompanyDivision"
    LEFT JOIN "Office_CompanyDivisions" 
      ON "CompanyDivision"."ID" = "Office_CompanyDivisions"."CompanyDivisionID"
    LEFT JOIN "Section_SectionCompanyDivisions" 
      ON "Section_SectionCompanyDivisions"."CompanyDivisionID" = "CompanyDivision"."ID"
    WHERE "Section_SectionCompanyDivisions"."SectionID" = '.$SectionID.'
      AND "Office_CompanyDivisions"."OfficeID" = '.$this->ID);
```

Running it through the following code returns a dataobject:

```
$output = array();
if ($query) {
    foreach ($query as $item) {
        $output[] = array(
            'Title' => $item['Title'],
            'DivisionPhoneNumber' => $item['DivisionPhoneNumber']
        );
    }
}

    return $output;
}
```

The returned dataobject via `Debug::show($output);` looks like this:

```
0 =
    Title =
    Widget Fluffing
    DivisionPhoneNumber =
    06 666 6666
```

Yet the following template code doesn't work:

```
<% loop FilteredCompanyDivisions($Top.ID) %>
  <li>
    <i class="icon-phone"></i> 
    <a href="tel:$DivisionPhoneNumber">$DivisionPhoneNumber</a> - $Title
  </li>
<% end_loop %>
```

...and returns this HTML:

```
<li><i class="icon-phone"></i> <a href="tel:"></a> - </li>
```

What am I doing wrong & how can I display a custom SQL as a template loop in Silverstripe?

Comment: Do you return `$output` at the end of your function? It'd be great if you could provide the full example

Comment: @RobbieAverill - yes ````return $output;```` is at the end of the function. Have updated my code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ArrayList` and `ArrayData` instead of returning a php array.

```
$output = ArrayList::create();
if ($query) {
    foreach ($query as $item) {
        $output->push( ArrayData::create(array(
            'Title' => $item['Title'],
            'DivisionPhoneNumber' => $item['DivisionPhoneNumber']
        )));
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. I had tried using ArrayList with the same result as native php - but my syntax was a bit off.

Comment: @BaronGrivet No worries :)